# force mdadm to be read-only on disk failure

Tags: mdadm

Is it possible to configure mdadm to become read-only when a drive fails?

I want to leave users with the most robust mdadm failure notification system. I've seen people ignoring a "degraded array" messages for a year, with obvious consequences. So a read-only filesystem is perhaps the most robust way, and does not require monitoring an email etc.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the mdadm man page, I believe that this functionality is not built in to mdadm - and indeed, I don't think that an mdadm drive that is in use can even be forced into readonly mode.

You can probably hack a script together and add an option PROGRAM /path/to/script to /etc/mdadm.conf.  Parameter 1 is, I believe, the event and parameter 2 is the device.  (note I have not tested this)

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find the info either... but I have seen read-only mdadm arrays on failure. But not always. I tested it by inducing a failed drive, and nothing happened. Maybe someone else will have more insights.